# UNIX: how to change group of read-only file system

Tags: permissions, group

I am trying to change the group of a file that I (`user123`) am an owner of but I am getting an error.  It won't let me change the directory permissions, either.  It keeps saying the file system is read-only.  I don't understand why it won't let me change permissions of a directory of which I am the owner!

```
(user123) @ subdomain.example.org [/dev/sudo/app/prog/id]
$ ls -la
total 3
drwxr-sr-x 2 user app 1024 Jun 18 11:12 etc

(user123) @ subdomain.example.org [/dev/sudo/app/prog/id]
$ chgrp mygroup etc/
chgrp: changing group of `etc/': Read-only file system
```

Comment: It tells you why.  The filesystem is mounted readonly.  Re-mount it RW and then chgrp.

Comment: Exactly. It's not that you don't have permission to change it, it's that the thing has been mounted as read only so it can't store new owner information.

Comment: That makes sense!  I didn't mount this before.  What's the command to re-mount?

Comment: Well, you'll need to use `mount` on its own to find out how the file system was mounted.  Then you run `umount /dev/whatever` to unmount it; then you run `mount ...options except -o ro... /dev/whatever` to (re)mount it.  All done as `root`, probably.  This is the low-level way to do it; there may be a better, high-level way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's strange that your root directory is mounted read-only. Was your system started normally or were there any "glitches" during boot? What runlevel are you at? (`who -r` if you're not sure)

In any case, you can remount the root directory read-write using

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```